# How can I prevent hot-linking to my files in public storage?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, google-cloud-storage, hotlinking

I have an NGINX server(with a wordpress site) and use Google Cloud Storage to feed my content. I have noticed sites hot-linking to my files without any attribution.

I suppose I need:

1. to make my links expire after a while so that the are no good after a while
2. for my wordpress site to pass an AUTH TOKEN to permit access to my files
3. for my google cloud storage not to feed a file unless its coming from the correct REFERRER?

How would someone accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods of controlling access to GCS buckets and/or individual objects, you need to study them to see which one fits your case best. From [Access Control Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/):

> You can control who has access to your Cloud Storage buckets and
>   objects as well as what level of access they have. Below is a summary
>   of the access control options available to you, along with links to
>   learning more about each:
>
> - [Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam): Grant access to buckets as well as bulk access to a bucket's objects. IAM
>     permissions give you broad control over your projects and buckets, but
>     not fine-grained control over individual objects. For a reference of
>     IAM permissions and roles specific to Cloud Storage, as well as which
>     permissions allow users to run JSON and XML methods on buckets and
>     objects, see the [IAM Reference pages](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-reference). To learn how to use IAM
>     permissions, see [Using IAM Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions).
> - [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists): Grant read or write access to users for individual buckets or objects. In most cases, you should use
>     IAM permissions instead of ACLs. Use ACLs only when you need
>     fine-grained control over individual objects. To learn how to use
>     ACLs, see [Create and Manage Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists).
> - [Signed URLs (query string authentication)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls): Give time-limited read or write access to an object through a URL you generate. Anyone
>     with whom you share the URL can access the object for the duration of
>     time you specify, regardless of whether or not they have a Google
>     account. Learn how to create signed URLs:
>
>   - [with gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-gsutil).
>   - [with a program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program).
> - [Signed Policy Documents](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument): Specify what can be uploaded to a bucket. Policy documents allow greater control over size, content
>     type, and other upload characteristics than signed URLs, and can be
>     used by website owners to allow visitors to upload files to Google
>     Cloud Storage.
> - [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security): Provide granular, attribute-based access control to mobile and web apps using the [Firebase SDKs for
>     Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). For example, you can specify who can upload or
>     download objects, how large an object can be, or when an object can be
>     downloaded.
>
> These options are not mutually exclusive. For example, you can use
>   ACLs to generally give private access to a bucket, but then create a
>   signed URL or policy document that allows anyone you choose to access
>   a resource within the bucket, bypassing the ACL mechanism.

Comment: Yup Signed URLS is what I was looking for. Thanks for the HELP

Answer (score -3):

Putting the following information in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://hpmouse.googlepages.com/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
```

Line 2 & 3 Are sites that you want to allow linking your images.
Line 4: File Formats to block linking

Comment: I use NGINX so there is no HTACCESS, and even if I did the videos are on Google Cloud Storage. Thanks anyways.